# How to insert data from String in table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have on table **PersonDetail** which contains NAME and AGE as column.
I am using one application which is taking all data as String by comma and pipe separated value like **'Acton,58|Nairi,20|Sara,14|Denny,52'** (Format is same as given)

I want to insert that data into table(PersonDetail) but I don't know how can I separate it as a NAME and AGE.

Some one suggested me to create function which can separate the data, But i have no idea to do it.
Can any one give me suggestion??
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use the application to parse the data.  Or read it in directly from the file using `bulk import`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create Multi-statement table value function to separate the data.
you just need to insert each NAME and AGE into table type variable and after inserting you should return that table as given below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION UDF_InsertDataFromString
(
@dataString VARCHAR(5000)
)
RETURNS @insertedData TABLE
(
NAME VARCHAR(30),
AGE INT
)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pipeIndex INT,
            @commaIndex INT,
            @LENGTH INT,
            @NAME VARCHAR(100),
            @AGE INT
    SELECT @LENGTH = LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM(@dataString))),
           @dataString = RTRIM(LTRIM(@dataString))

    WHILE (@LENGTH <> 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @LENGTH = LEN(@dataString),
               @commaIndex = CHARINDEX(',', @dataString),
               @pipeIndex = CHARINDEX('|', @dataString)
        IF(@pipeIndex = 0) SET @pipeIndex = @LENGTH +1
        SELECT @NAME = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@dataString, 1, @commaIndex-1))),
               @AGE = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@dataString, @commaIndex+1, @pipeIndex-@commaIndex-1))),
               @dataString = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@dataString, @pipeIndex+1, @LENGTH-@commaIndex-1)))
            INSERT INTO @insertedData(NAME, AGE)    
            VALUES(@NAME, @AGE)
        SELECT @LENGTH = LEN(@dataString)       
    END
    RETURN
END
```

Now you can use this function while inserting data from string, you just need to pass string as parameter in function as given below.

```
DECLARE @personDetail TABLE(NAME VARCHAR(30), AGE INT)

INSERT INTO @personDetail(NAME, AGE)
SELECT NAME, AGE 
FROM dbo.UDF_InsertDataFromString('Acton,58|Nairi,20|Sara,14|Denny,52')

SELECT NAME, AGE
FROM @personDetail
```

Answer (score 1):

use this split func

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

and then use this query

```
DECLARE @x table ( id  int identity(1,1)
    ,                  str varchar(50) )
    DECLARE @str varchar(50)='Acton,58|Nairi,20|Sara,14|Denny,52'
    INSERT INTO @x
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@str ,'|')
    SELECT *
    from @x
    DECLARE @y int=(SELECT count(*)
    FROM @x)
    DECLARE @e varchar(50)
    DECLARE @b varchar(50)
    DECLARE @c varchar(50)
    WHILE @y!=0
    BEGIN
        set @e =(SELECT str
        FROM @x
        where id=@y)
        set @b =(substring(@e,1,(charindex(',',@e)-1)))
        set @c = (substring(@e,(charindex(',',@e)+1),len(@e)-charindex(',',@e)))


        INSERT INTO PersonDetail
        SELECT distinct @b
        ,               @c
        FROM @x
        SET @y=@y-1
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can create your own function.

just you need to apply different string function for that

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms181984.aspx